# Google Cloud DLP API Call

Tags: google-chrome, gcloud, google-cloud-dlp, google-dl-platform

I am using a free tier google account and i want to call any DLP API for text/image scanning for some demo purpose. I see DLP service don't fall in the category of free tier service. is there any way to call dlp api using curl in active shell? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you use `curl`, but that does not change the Free Tier status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure thanks for the inputs. I created a service account and downloaded the json file from google cloud console. I am using that json and projectId to call DLP clients for scanning and its working fine now. One thing i am not sure about billing charges here. I created this small JAVA class from where i am calling DLP.

Answer (score 1):

You must [authenticate](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/auth) to the DLP API in order to use it.

You can curl the DLP API either [using an API key for unauthenticated access](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/auth#using_an_api_key_for_unauthenticated_access) or [bearer tokens using a service account](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/auth#bearer).

You can also check this [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/inspect-sensitive-text-api) for guidance.

Cloud DLP provides a set of features for inspecting and transforming data which is free up to 1GB and pricing will depend per content method inspection and transformation once it exceeds the 1GB of transformed or inspected data. Check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/pricing) for more information on its pricing.